# Can someone explain 搜噶斯耐 in internet speak?

Tags: pronunciation, internet-slang

I was chatting with a Chinese friend of mine whose english is a bit broken (not as nearly as much as my Mandarin is) & she wrote

> 搜噶斯耐

Which apparently means something like 'so that's it' in english.  As she explained, the reason for writing it this way is has something to do with the Japanese pronunciation of these words.  She mentioned that something similar occurs with:

> 针不搓

Can someone help me explain these idiosyncrasies in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 2):

- 搜噶斯耐 = そうですね (sou desu ne)

I'm not sure how *噶斯* becomes *desu* but hey here we are.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%AD)

> そうですね
> 1 that's so, isn't it so?
> 2 hmm (used to indicate that the listener has heard and understood)

---

针不戳 is a meme based off of poor pronunciation.

- 针不戳 = 真不错

The original sentence was:

> “针不戳，住在山里面针不戳”

Now people say it wrong on purpose to reference it.

Comment: 搜噶 sounds like そうが, not そうですね. I'm not sure if it is a typo from OP...

Comment: @tsh That’s what I originally thought too but if you look at the articles on Baidu Zhidao, etc. they all mention that 搜噶斯耐 and it’s variants equate to そうですね.

Comment: @tsh It may be because most Chinese hear this Japanese word in the TV series about World War II, and most of the actors who acts Japanese soldiers are Chinese who have bad pronunciation... There are a number of this kind of TV series every year. The Japanese they speak is not real Japanese.

Comment: It may also be a confused mixture of そうが and そうですね to equate something like そうがすね...which is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

The first situation mainly occurs in the context of incoming foreign words, because for most beginners, it is the most convenient and efficient to use native pronunciation to describe a new word, because Chinese is ideographic and spelled for native Chinese speakers. The phonetic symbols are not as fluent as spelling Chinese characters. In addition to the memes on the Internet and intentional spelling irregularities (of course, most of the reasons are not understanding Japanese grammar), which led to the combination of soga and sou desu ne"搜噶斯耐"

真不戳 is a meme, it comes from a short online video, in the video, a person (eggplant, CS:GO player, famous for the iconic WDNMD [expletive, literally translated as fxxk your mother but has evolved without How much ridicule and offensiveness, mostly used for self-deprecating]) On vacation in the mountains, walked to the balcony and said 真不错,住在山里真不错(It’s nice, it’s nice to live in the mountains), because of his accent,真不错It’s pretty good, the word sounds more like真不戳, and quickly became a meme (due to the particularity of Chinese, the input method uses pinyin, so people can quickly find polyphonic characters), people began to send a lot of comments Homophones of zhen1 bu2 cuo4, such as 针不戳,振不辍,畛不搓(And netizens tend to use rare and alien characters to spell)